# firestore security-rule syntax: check if document name contains xyz

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a document whose name consists of two user keys, can I check whether the key of the querying user is included.

for example the user fvmAPXO4BYUVJYkeSxsgsgzjjs should have access to the document 2B0ABrxKgjkrefjCP8tuMgq12e4-fvmAPXO4BYUVJYkeSxsgsgzjjs

I need something like: `allow read, write: if document name contains ("request.auth.uid") ;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `matches()` as shown below:

```
match /collection/{docId} {
  allow read: if docId.matches(".*"+request.auth.uid+".*");
}
```

This regular expression will simply check if `request.auth.uid` is present in the document ID.